# CQL from Cassandra Model (datastax driver: python)

Tags: python, cassandra

Datastax Cassandra Driver (Python): Is there a way to generate CQL files from the data models we create? As an example if I have a data model:

```
class ExampleModel(Model):
example_id      = columns.UUID(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4)
example_type    = columns.Integer(index=True)
created_at      = columns.DateTime()
description     = columns.Text(required=False)
```

I know I can create table in Cassandra using the `sync_table` but my aim here is to derive the equivalent CQL statements for the create table statement generated from the model above. Is there a way?

Comment: You can create the table and then with `cqlsh` you can `describe yourtable;` to get the corresponding `CREATE TABLE...` statements.

Comment: @xmas79 Thanks for your help. I must admit this is what also crossed my mind before I posted the question. I am looking for a way to obtain this without leaving the programming environment in Python. One solution is: issue a `desc table` from python, is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are okay creating the table, the most robust way would be to sync the table, then use the driver's metadata API to reproduce the string.

[Cluster.metadata.keyspaces[ks].tables[t]](http://datastax.github.io/python-driver/api/cassandra/cluster.html#cassandra.cluster.Cluster.metadata)
and
[TableMetadata.export_as_string](http://datastax.github.io/python-driver/api/cassandra/metadata.html#cassandra.metadata.TableMetadata.export_as_string)

This is the exact code that generates the `desc` output for cqlsh.

Alternatively, you can avoid creating the table by using the cqlengine management function that generates CQL from these models:

[cassandra.cqlengine.management._get_create_table](https://github.com/datastax/python-driver/blob/master/cassandra/cqlengine/management.py#L389)

Note that this is not part of the API, and very likely to change as it is replaced with the core driver metadata equivalent.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer! I was looking for ways to do database migration (something like what alembic does for postgress). I believe there is none officially supported by Datastax drivers yet, but found some that work on CQL, hence the question.